# Keyword extraction from a python code using python

Tags: python

I wish to write a code which accepts a python code as input and processes it to extract keywords from the input. But I am not sure about how I can extract sub strings from a statement like

```
print("hello world")
```

I tried using substring by using the following code but its not working...

```
import keyword


test_list = ["print('Hello World')"]

print("The original list is : " + str(test_list))

res = []
for sub in test_list:
    for word in sub.split():

        if keyword.iskeyword(word):
            res.append(word)

print("Extracted Keywords : " + str(res))
```

Comment: You’re not the first person to ask how to build an interpreter.

Comment: If you're looking to parse Python, then Python actually [has a module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for that. If you're looking to write your own language, then you'll need to write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

Just for this example of yours,

```
import keyword
import re

test_list = ["print('Hello World')"]

print("The original list is : " + str(test_list))
res = []
for sub in test_list:    
    out = re.findall("[a-zA-z]*", sub)
    for word in out:
        if keyword.iskeyword(word):
            res.append(word)

print("Extracted Keywords : " + str(res))
```

You should look at extracting the alphabetical words, first. Once you are able to get the words ,find whether they are keywords.
Word extraction can be done using regex module, as I have done above.